# I'm Lost: I'd like to use client-certificates to authenticate users' access to our web server

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl, authentication, certificate

(Windows Server 2008)

We have a web server that we'd like to limit access to. I thought a good way to do this would be to issue certificates to ours users.

Unfortunately, [This IIS & Tutorial](http://blogs.iis.net/rlucero/archive/2008/05/23/iis-7-walkthrough-one-to-one-client-certificate-mapping-configuration.aspx) either did not work or I failed to implement it properly. With or without an installed client certificate, I get 403 Access Forbidden.

**What is the easiest way to accomplish what I'm after?**

If I have to spend an hour trying to figure out the correct way to issue certificates from my server, I'd rather just buy Godaddy cert's. I issued a certificate that was successfully installed on some client machines, but as I said above, 403 Access Forbidden.

Any tips? I'm truly lost and can't find any more resources to get me to my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you mentioned appears to be a rough, but correct, overview for doing exactly what you're looking for. I don't think there are any easier alternatives for this.

You're going to have to rely on functionality built into a web-server, or maybe a custom tool, to solve your problem. I don't believe there's any easier or more user friendly options - all of the tools and/or native options for solving your problem are at roughly the same level of difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to get the GoDaddy cert.   First, you can create your own self signed cert for free (as a test).  Once you get things working then you can finally buy the GoDaddy cert.  Otherwise you are buying something your not sure you will use...

Also, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816794